# VBA intersect row and column

Tags: excel, vba, intersect

i am writing code to update spreadsheet cell value with intersect function. i have below code that search UserForm3.txtchangenumber in range I1 to AZA1 (worksheet "Cost") and search userform1.txtselectedpart in range E4 to E250(worksheet "Cost"). i would like to populate cell in (worksheet "Cost") when both search intersect by using intersect function.

below is code what i have right now. but it gives me run time erroe 1004  method range of object _global failed.

can you pl help me to understand what is error by correcting below code.

```
[CODE=vba]Private Sub txtdelta_AfterUpdate()



Dim vrech As Range

Dim lColumn As Range

Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cost")





'Dim colonne As Long

        'colonne = Me.ComboBox1.Value

Set lColumn = sh.Range("i2:AZa2").Find(UserForm3.txtchangenumber, , xlValues, xlWhole) 'LookIn:=xlValues)

Set vrech = sh.Range("E4:E250").Find(UserForm1.txtselectedpart, , xlValues, xlWhole) 'LookIn:=xlValues)





     Intersect(Range("vrech"), Range("col")) = UserForm1.txtdelta.Value







End Sub[/CODE]
```

Comment: Please, insert a line after the `vrech` variable load: `If vrech is nothing then Stop`. Does your code stop on this line?

Comment: Is "col" a named range?

Comment: it is stop after Column. i have modified code as below to see where i have problem and it cannot find column,

Comment: Set lColumn = sh.Range("i2:AZa2").Find(UserForm3.txtchangenumber, , xlValues, xlWhole) 'LookIn:=xlValues)
Set vrech = sh.Range("E4:E250").Find(UserForm1.txtselectedpart, , xlValues, xlWhole) 'LookIn:=xlValues)

If vrech Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Row not found"
ElseIf lColumn Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Column not found"
Else
    Intersect(vrech.EntireRow, lColumn.EntireColumn) = UserForm1.txtdelta.Value

Comment: Do you mean `lColumn`? How does it stop? Do you mean at my suggested line? It should be inserted  **"after the vrech variable load"**...

Comment: i have added below code after the vrech variable load. it does not stop at vrech. it stops after icolumn variable load.                                                                                              If vrech Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Row not found" ' it is ok. it finds the rows.
ElseIf lColumn Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Column not found". this is where code stops.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** If you put something in quotes ("col"), you ask VBA to see this as string, not as variable name. So you try to access a Range named `col` and that doesn't exist.

**(2)** What you mean is probably to access the column that you identified with `lColumn`. Beside the fact that this name is different: You access a complete column in Excel with `lColumn.EntireColumn`. Similar, you get the complete row with `vrech.EntireRow`.

**(3)** If you want to go for `Intersect`, you could for example write something like this

```
Intersect(vRech, lColumn) = UserForm1.txtdelta.Value
```

**(4)** A different way is to use the `Cells`-object - maybe easier to understand:

```
sh.cells(vrech.Row, lColumn.Column) = UserForm1.txtdelta.Value
```

You should also add a check if both `Find`-command where successfull, else you will get a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for help, below code works as intended. there was an issue with column reference.

```
Private Sub txtdelta_AfterUpdate()

Dim vrech As Range
Dim lColumn As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cost")

Set lColumn = sh.Range("i1:AZa1").Find(UserForm1.txtdummy.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)

Set vrech = sh.Range("E4:E250").Find(UserForm1.txtselectedpart.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
If vrech Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Row not found"
ElseIf lColumn Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Column not found"
Else
    Intersect(vrech.EntireRow, lColumn.EntireColumn) = UserForm1.txtdelta.Value
End If
End Sub
```